# Error:Initialization of the JSF runtime either failed or did not occurr when adding a JSF Page to Web Project in Jdeveloper

Tags: java, jsf, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I get the following error when i add a JSF Page to my web project. If i try to add the JSF Page to Generic Project for example it will be added fine. Below is a snapshot of the error.

[image: Error Shot]

Comment: which jsf version and jdevloper version r you using?

Comment: also try to use latest trinidad.jar